# Composer Install Fails

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm facing an issue while attempting to run `composer install` for a GitHub project.

Here's a summary of the steps I've taken:

1. Downloaded the project as a ZIP file.
2. Extracted and compressed the files.
3. Composer and PHP are already installed on my machine.

However, running `composer install` results in the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

I'm uncertain about how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Can someone provide guidance on the necessary steps to address this problem? Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

**Additional Information:**

- Operating System: ***Windows 10***
- Composer Version: ***1.10.27***
- PHP Version: ***8.2.0***

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: You should post your composer.json

Comment: The "requirements could not be resolved" message typically comes with quite a bit more output, too.

Comment: Your PHP version is the LTS as of this moment but just maybe the requirements if your project requirement is only at 7.4 or 7.3. Check the version in your composer.json.

Comment: PHP 8.2.0 is pretty outdated, the same applies to Composer v1 - why not use any more current versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some of the required packages are not available for certain conditions.

Try the following command:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes you think that running with `--ignore-platform-reqs` is a good idea?